# Yii2 - Bad Request (#400) | Frontend and backend cookies

Tags: php, cookies, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

The issue appears only when I open `frontend` and `backend` in the same `browser`.

**Scenario:**

> Interact with Backend -> Switched Tab -> Interact with Frontend ->
>   Switched Tab Back -> Interact with Backend -> Bad Request (#400)

**Cookie Backend**

```
'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_backendIdentity',
                'path'=>'/admin',
                'httpOnly' => true,
            ],
```

**Cookie Frontend**

```
'identityCookie' => [
                    'name' => '_frontendIdentity',
                    'path'=>'/', 
                    'httpOnly' => true,
                ],
```

**Session Backend**

```
'session' => [
            'name' => 'session_backend'
        ],
```

**Session Frontend**

```
'session' => [
            'name' => 'session_frontend'
        ],
```

Comment: Start by checking relevant logfiles to get an actual error _message_, to find out what the reason behind the 400 is.

Comment: error log is not showing anything, it looks that issue is with cookies as it only occurs in the same browser with multiple tabs.

Comment: Which log did you check? Yes, it might have something to do with the cookies - but that 400 error must still be raised by the system somewhere, and that means it should log what the cause of the error was somewhere as well.

Comment: I have checked error_log file at the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the issue of `CSRF` that are different on the both `frontend`  and `backend` so when a browser storing the `session` of same application have 2 different `CSRF` then one of the application will get `Bad Request (#400)`

Comment: Thank you @indra your clue helped me sort out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to `@indra shastri`

**For those who are facing same issue:**

Adding the following resolved my problem.

**Backend config/main.php**

```
'request' => [
                'cookieValidationKey' => '[DIFFERENT UNIQUE KEY]',
                'csrfParam' => '_backendCSRF',
            ],
```

**Frontend config/main.php**

```
'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => '[RANDOM KEY HERE]',
            'csrfParam' => '_frontendCSRF',
        ],
```