# Yii2 CSRF token time period increase

Tags: php, yii2, csrf

Currently I am working on Yii2 and when I go to form submit after some time then Yii2 redirect to bad request, I think there is CSRF token expire so my question is, how increase CSRF token life in Yii2?

How can we do with form submit with long time and CSRF token also validate?

CSRF token validation disable is working fine in my code but I didn't want to disable it.

No need to code show here, I think.

Comment: if i remember correctly, the current csrf token is stored in the php-session. so increasing session lifetime should lead to a longer valid csrf token

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You can check, i was face same problem and get idea from there :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672186/yii2-bad-request-400-frontend-and-backend-cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use frontend and backend as different cookie and session

***Cookie Backend***

```
'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_backendIdentity',
                'path'=>'/admin',
                'httpOnly' => true,
            ],
```

**Cookie Frontend**

```
'identityCookie' => [
                    'name' => '_frontendIdentity',
                    'path'=>'/', 
                    'httpOnly' => true,
                ],
```

**Session Backend**

```
'session' => [
            'name' => 'session_backend'
        ],
```

**Session Frontend**

```
'session' => [
            'name' => 'session_frontend'
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can increase csrf token expiry time by adding following code in config/web.php file. From below code csrf token valid for one hour only. Can increase time as per your need.**

```
'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'Key Here',
        'csrfCookie' => [
            'expire' => time() + 3600,
            'secure' => true,
        ],
    ],
```